# Setting session timeout in Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo

I need to set a session timeout in Odoo 8. This could be done in Odoo 7 by modifying the time in session_gc method in http.py. But I tried the same in Odoo 7 and it doesn't seem to be working. I would like to know if anyone has a solution to this. The following is the code that I modified in openerp 7 to get this done.

```
def session_gc(session_store):
if random.random() < 0.001:
    # we keep session one week
    last_week = time.time() - x
    for fname in os.listdir(session_store.path):
        path = os.path.join(session_store.path, fname)
        try:
            if os.path.getmtime(path) < last_week:
                os.unlink(path)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

Here x is the no of seconds for session timeout. This seems to be working fine when i'm running on port 9069 but on the default port, it throws up an error.

P.S: Either this, or I need a method to logout a user based on a particular date. I have done this by overriding the authenticate method but the problem arises if the user leaves it logged in. The authenticate checks only upon login time.

Thanks And Regards,

Yaseen Shareef

Answer (score 0):

the same function is available in odoo 8. The only difference is that the http.py file is located at the root of odoo directory and not in addons/web .
One more thing. If you server doesnt have a heavy request, it could be better for you to increase the top limit of the random value : for example

if random.random() < 0.1:

Answer (score -1):

Our team, called "ITS-1", has created a module named "web_session".

It is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/ITS-1/web_session

It gets users latest action datetime, stores it in the Users table and uses this value to calculate, whether the user should stay logged in the system. The session length parameter can be set in Settings -> Configuration -> General Settings and the required format is HH:MM, the default is 02:00 (2 hours). Also, you can see the latest action datetime for each user in Users list view.

We would be grateful for some feedback and improvement suggestions.

Hope this helps!